# How to group by adding an additional column stating group

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a supplier table where in it contains all the supplier specific information (total 10 columns). I am trying to group them in such a way that it should be ordered by the creation of the record i.e. DateCreated and where SupplierNumber is same and a new column should be created as Type and group that same SupplierNumber and DateCreated as Group1 and so on as shown below.
Sample Table Data :

```
SupplierName    SupplierNumber  DateCreated
Supplier4       50006155        07/13/2022 08:09PM
Supplier1       50000253        07/18/2022 10:19PM
Supplier5       50003200        07/13/2022 08:23PM
Supplier1       50000253        07/18/2022 10:19PM
Supplier3       50005963        07/13/2022 08:06PM
Supplier2       50001781        07/20/2022 02:11PM
Supplier3       50005963        07/13/2022 08:06PM
Supplier4       50006155        07/13/2022 08:09PM
Supplier5       50003200        07/13/2022 08:23PM
Supplier2       50001781        07/20/2022 02:11PM
```

Example : it should be in below format:

```
Type        SupplierName    SupplierNumber  DateCreated
Group 1     Supplier1       50000253        07/18/2022 10:19PM
Group 1     Supplier1       50000253        07/18/2022 10:19PM
Group 2     Supplier2       50001781        07/20/2022 02:11PM
Group 2     Supplier2       50001781        07/20/2022 02:11PM
Group 3     Supplier3       50005963        07/13/2022 08:06PM
Group 3     Supplier3       50005963        07/13/2022 08:06PM
Group 4     Supplier4       50006155        07/13/2022 08:09PM
Group 4     Supplier4       50006155        07/13/2022 08:09PM
Group 5     Supplier5       50003200        07/13/2022 08:23PM
Group 5     Supplier5       50003200        07/13/2022 08:23PM
```

Solution Tried:

```
Select SupplierNumber,DateCreated  from Supplier
GROUP BY SupplierNumber,DateCreated
ORDER BY DateCreated, SupplierNumber
```

Thank You in Advance,

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish... please provide sample starting data that should be used to produce your desired results as shown.

Comment: I have removed the image to reserve as said and also have posted sample data which i have and the expected output. - Thanks

Comment: You don't need to group, you're not trying to aggregate your data. Just create a calculated column `replace(SupplierNumber,'Supplier','Group ')` . (PS strange to call your column `SupplierNumber` when its a string).

Comment: I don't follow what you want to group. "I am trying to group them in such a way that it should be ordered by", grouping is not the same as sorting. You could get the result you want with `REPLACE(SupplierNumber, 'Supplier', 'Group ')`, with an `ORDER BY SupplierName`

Comment: But how would i create a new column Type with values Group1 , Group2 .. according to the date and timestamp depending on the same supplier.

Comment: Why are we using a Replace Function here ?

Comment: Your sample data says to create a "Group 5" for "Supplier5" hence the replace. Maybe you need to update your sample data to illustrate your full problem?

Comment: OMG.. That is just a Supplier Name , Ok Never mind.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select concat('Group ', dense_rank() over(order by SupplierName, DateCreated)) as Type
      ,*
from   t
```

| Type | SupplierName | SupplierNumber | DateCreated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Group 1 | Supplier1 | 50000253 | 07/18/2022 10:19PM |
| Group 1 | Supplier1 | 50000253 | 07/18/2022 10:19PM |
| Group 2 | Supplier2 | 50001781 | 07/20/2022 02:11PM |
| Group 2 | Supplier2 | 50001781 | 07/20/2022 02:11PM |
| Group 3 | Supplier3 | 50005963 | 07/13/2022 08:06PM |
| Group 3 | Supplier3 | 50005963 | 07/13/2022 08:06PM |
| Group 4 | Supplier4 | 50006155 | 07/13/2022 08:09PM |
| Group 4 | Supplier4 | 50006155 | 07/13/2022 08:09PM |
| Group 5 | Supplier5 | 50003200 | 07/13/2022 08:23PM |
| Group 5 | Supplier5 | 50003200 | 07/13/2022 08:23PM |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9UFpLy3N?hide=2)

Comment: In this solution , Group is not set as per the First Date Created , It should be grouped based on the First Created Date & the supplier

Comment: If you see my output it should be sorted by date (having same date time and first created) and same supplier then it should be group 1 and similarly group it as 2, 3 based on the same date time and supplier.